# Only allow certain domain to access web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that I have created.

I want to ensure that only certain domain can access this data, I don't want everyone accessing it. Is this something that is achievable? Is it recommended? How would one go about doing this or can anyone point me into the right direction - articles etc...

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

There is build in "CORS support for ASP.NET Web API" version 2 (MVC5):
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own method that validates if the request comes from a certain domain. But I wouldn't recommend using it as security for sensitive data since a domain is easy to spoof. I would strongly recommend to stick with default authentication mechanisms and not invent your own, but validating for a certain domain could be an extra validation.

You could validate the referer domain like this:

```
var currentReferrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
if (currentReferrer != requiredReferrer)
{
            // Not the right domain.
}
```

But please take the following in account when you do so:

> Checking the HTTP Referer header to see if the request is coming from
>   an authorized page is commonly used for embedded network devices
>   because it does not increase memory requirements. However a request
>   that omits the Referer header must be treated as unauthorized because
>   an attacker can suppress the Referer header by issuing requests from
>   FTP or HTTPS URLs. This strict Referer validation may cause issues
>   with browsers or proxies that omit the Referer header for privacy
>   reasons. Also, old versions of Flash (before 9.0.18) allow malicious
>   Flash to generate GET or POST requests with arbitrary HTTP request
>   headers using CRLF Injection.[22] Similar CRLF injection
>   vulnerabilities in a client can be used to spoof the referrer of an
>   HTTP request.

From: [Wikipedia: Cross-site request forgery prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention)